# Shadow in enumerate

Tags: enumerate

I want to put exercices' numbers in a sort of shadowbox, just as shown in the picture, but I really didn't know how to do that...

[image: rate]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! The `enumitem` package allows you to wrap the numbers in macros. `tcolorbox` allows you to design pretty much any box you can imagine. That is, while there are other options to create shadowed boxes, if you want to have a highly flexible package this might be your preferred choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\numbox}[1][]{enhanced,colback=white,arc=0pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,
left=1ex,right=1ex,box align=base,drop shadow=black}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\numbox{\itshape\bfseries\arabic*}]
 \item Something.
 \item Honey liquor.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `fancybox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\setlength{\shadowsize}{2.5pt}
\newcommand{\shadbox}[1]{\raisebox{-0.38\height}{\protect\shadowbox{\hskip0.3em\itshape\bfseries#1\hskip 0.3em}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\shadbox{\arabic*}]
 \item Trouver la limite de $\Bigl(\sin\frac{n\pi}{6n + 1}\Bigr)$
 \item Étudier la suite $(u_n)$ définie par
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]